# How to format webpage before it is loaded javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok. I am making a website on github using html and javascript. Earlier, I was using a template to make simple, formatted webpages. I got it to work, but it has an annoying bug: the unformatted webpage shows up before the formatted one. I am using the latest version of jquery (2.1.4) hosted from google and the javascript below:

```
var heading = document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML;
var pghead = document.getElementById("pghead").innerHTML;
var pgtext = document.getElementById("pgtext").innerHTML;
var template = function () {
  var tmp = null;
  $.ajax({
      'async': false,
      'dataType': 'html',
      'url': "https://jediguy13.github.io/template.html",
      'success': function (data) {
          tmp = data;
      }
  });
  return tmp.split("derp");
}();
document.write(template[0] + heading + template[1] + pghead + template[2] + pgtext + template[3]);
document.getElementById("heading").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("pghead").innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById("pgtext").innerHTML = "";
```

And here's a sample webpage:

```
<div id="heading">Test</div>
<div id="pghead">Test</div>
<div id="pgtext">This is some text in the main body of the webpage</div>
```

As you can see from the `'async': false.` line, Jquery is requesting the template webpage at the same time as the main thread. However, there is always a slight delay in the formatting. I'm betting it is because the `document.write` is called near the end. What is a better way to get the browser to display just the formatted page?

Example page: [website](https://jediguy13.github.io/Projects)

Comment: This is standard. Server side whatevers first, then HTML, then Javascript takes over. If you need Javascript on the server, use Node, otherwise use whatever you are using on the server (PHP, .NET, whatever) to deal with this formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `document.write()`. Ever. If you have an HTML snippet, just attach it to the desired node like this:

```
$("body").html(template[0] + ...);
```

If the page is originally empty and all the content is loaded with AJAX, then you'll see a white page that then is filled with your code.

In your case it will NOT be empty as I can guess, so **you have to clear the HTML immediately after you fetch it**:

```
heading = $("#heading").html();
$("#heading").html("");
```

This will minimize the original exposure of the HTML.

At this point you may want to fade it in slowly, like this:

```
$("body").hide();
// ... make AJAX call and attach it as shown above
$("body").fadeIn();
```

The `fadeIn()` is a touch of class you might as well replace with `show()`.

Make the AJAX call asynchronous and put all of this into the AJAX `success()` method.

This is all together in a complete rewrite. Just copy+paste and tell me if it's working:

```
var heading, pghead, pgtext;

$("body").hide();

heading = $("#heading").html();
pghead = $("#pghead").html();
pgtext = $("#pgtext").html();
$("#heading").html("");
$("#pghead").html("");
$("#pgtext").html("");

$.ajax({
  'async': true,
  'dataType': 'html',
  'url': "https://jediguy13.github.io/template.html",
  'success': function (data) {
      template = data.split("derp");
      $("body").html(template[0] + heading + template[1] + pghead + template[2] + pgtext + template[3]);
      $("body").fadeIn();
  }
});
```

Comment: I also had to use @James G. 's answer to get it to not show text at all. The problem is that the javascript is still running after the page has loaded.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so first off I'm going to say you shouldn't rely on JS to format your entire page unless you're hosting a single-page application, and even then... probably not the entire page.

To answer your question, the only way to not show the unformatted page is to hide your content until the page loads. Give your `body` tag or container `style='display:none;'` and then when your JS has finished executing, show the content with by calling something like `$('body').show()`.

Answer (score 0):

one of my favourite tricks is to place a loader div and keep the content hidden and the loader visible until all JS based layout changes are completed. provided you have the luxury of using Jquery (or CSS3) you can use an easing effect on the opacity to give it a much better feel.